# OSX - Background Items Added - Software from Citrix Online LLC

Tags: citrix, macos-ventura

Does anybody know how to uninstall/delete Citrix Online from OSX? I keep getting the following message:[image: Background Items Added]

I've downloaded Citrix Workspace App and ran Uninstall, didn't help, I've downloaded Citrix Receiver and ran Uninstall, didn't help... I'm getting sick of this message... I've disabled it in Login Items - but still....I want to remove it from my computer....but how do I do that? Does anybody know?

[image: Login Items]

Comment: seems like this is a bug in MacOS - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254341579 https://superuser.com/questions/1758548/citrix-complete-removal-on-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to delete the citrix item allowed in background and get rid of the annoying notification - it turned out to be an item added by [goto meeting](https://www.goto.com/meeting) that I deleted from the system a long time ago... I found and deleted the following file located in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

```
com.citrixonline.GoToMeeting.G2MUpdate.plist
```

and that made the `Citrix Online LLC` item to disappear from items allowed in background in system settings/login items. (I also found and deleted `com.logmein.GoToMeeting.G2MUpdate.plist` in the same folder, because I don't have goto meeting on my computer anymore)

Comment: Thank you! As you did, I downloaded & ran the uninstaller for Citrix Workspace. But the message didn't stop appearing until I removed ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.logmein.GoToMeeting.G2MUpdate.plist

Answer (score -1):

Have same problem. Even after going into system folder and deleting everything I could find

Comment: If you are also facing the same issue, Either add it in comment, or upvote the question. Don't mention in the answer. If it is answer, write it clearly. I agree you don't know enough reputation to vote or comment, still don't reply in answer